# Disable Devise sign_in redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, devise

I'm building an API on top of my rails 3.2 application.

When I login to `api/login` using the right parameters for the first time, it works great. 
But when I attempt to repeat the exact same operation again, I'm already logged in and it renders me the html of my app's homepage. I guess it's because my application is set up to redirect to this page after log in. Can I modify my `api/sessions_controller.rb` such that it does not redirect to anything :

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:create]
  before_filter :ensure_params_exist, :only => [:create]

  respond_to :json

  def create
    build_resource
    resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(login: params[:login])
    return invalid_login_attempt unless resource

    if resource.valid_password?(params[:password])
      sign_in("user", resource) # I would like to disable redirection here 
      generate_authentication_token(resource)
      render :json => {success: true, ...}
      return
    end

    invalid_login_attempt
  end
```

**Edit**

```
    def invalid_login_attempt
      warden.custom_failure!
      render :json=> {success: false, message: "Error with your login or password" + params.inspect}, :status=>401
    end
```

Comment: What is `invalid_login_attempt`?

Comment: just handling invalid parameters - see edit

Comment: Just found the gist you took this from. In case you hadn't noticed, it's over 2 years old, so it could have been written for a much older version of Devise than the one you are using. Can you clarify what this API is intended for? I.e, is it the backend for a single-page application or is it designed to be consumed by other applications?

Comment: It's the backend for a single-page application

Comment: Most of the examples I have seen just use the standard html templates for authentication rather than trying to replicate them in Backbone or Ember (or whatever else).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question because I found one way to do this :

```
#sessions_controller.rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  sign_in_url = url_for(:action => 'show_info', :controller => 'sessions', :only_path => false, :protocol => 'http')
end
```

And then make `sessions#show_info` return the exact same information the `create` function will return. Not sure if this is the best way though

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you in any way? 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in
Also, not redirecting anywhere after sign in is not a very healthy workflow. In a logged in session, you shouldn't be able to reach a sign in screen to input credentials. You can only reach it after sign out.

Comment: Not really. I would like no redirection at all, just 'sign in' the user

Comment: You could make your own sign in like in the tutorial:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-signin_success
But this would not involve devise anymore